# How lymphocytes in lymphatic system get oxygen?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, proteins, cellular-respiration, immune-system

We know that the gas-transporting protein hemoglobin is absent from the lymphatic system. So, how does gas transportation takes place in lymphatic system? Is mere diffusion from surrounding blood vessels sufficient for lymphocytes and lymphatic endothelium to survive?

Comment: Besides carrier transport of oxygen and/or other gases that hemoglobin binds in the blood, there is also dissolved oxygen present in the plasma - this would also be present in the lymph fluid despite a lack of hemoglobin. With the complex network of arteries/arterioles/capillaries that deliver oxygen to tissues, do you think that lymph transport of gases is even important?

Comment: @Vance Yes , I think it's important because how does the cells forming lymph vessels(endothelium of vessels), lymphocytes in vessels and nodes get the required amount of oxygen?

Comment: @JM97 Dissolved gaseous oxygen moves fairly freely over short distances...lymph vessels will never be far from other vessels, including capillaries. So, essentially the lymphatic vessels are fed the same way as any other organ tissue.

Comment: @BryanKrause what about lymph nodes?

Comment: @JM97 Lymph nodes are highly vascularized.

Comment: So oxygen dissolved in lymph will support myriad of lymphocytes of lymph node? I don't think that's sufficient considering the very large density of lymphocytes in the node.

Comment: @JM97 Lymph nodes are highly vascularized, as Bryan Krause said. That means lots of RBCs delivering lots of oxygen to the node and all of the cells contained therein. It doesn't matter if you *think* it's sufficient, in reality it is.